# package charmCli/cmd/ui/textInput is not in std

Tags: go

Cobra CLIの勉強をしているのですが、インポートでエラーが発生します。

package cmd

```
import (
    "charmCli/cmd/ui/textInput"

    tea "github.com/charmbracelet/bubbletea"
    "github.com/charmbracelet/lipgloss"
    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)
```

エラーは以下です

package charmCli/cmd/ui/textInput is not in std (C:\Program Files\Go\src\charmCli\cmd\ui\textInput)

"charmCli/cmd/ui/textInput"はローカル環境で同じプロジェクト内の別のフォルダのgoの関数を呼び出すために書きました。textInputのフォルダにgoファイルがあります。
import github.com/username/charmCli/cmd/ui/textInputと記述して
go modで以下のように記述してみました。

module your/module

go 1.15

require (
// 必要であれば他の依存モジュールをここに記述
)

replace github.com/Argorn5940/charmCli/cmd/ui/textinput => C:/Users/owner/go/workspace/charmCLI/cmd/ui/textinput

これでもエラーは解消されません。
プロジェクト構成は
charmCli--|
cmd
|  |
|  ui-textInput-gotest.go（インポート先）
test.go（インポート）
go buildするとどうも、C:\Program Files\Go\src\charmCli\cmd\ui\textinputを探しています。そこにはプロジェクトがありません。
C:/Users/owner/go/workspace/charmCLI/cmd/ui/textinputを探してくれません。
Gopathに問題があるのでしょうか？